# Jquery last row first column to be focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to focus the table's last row and it's first column cell is to be focus(Jquery focus event). It's possible

My code but it does not works:

```
 $('table#myTable tr:last td:first').focus();
```

Comment: do you have any input item in the first column?

Comment: what do you mean by focus?? is there any input in td or you want to highlight td itself.

Comment: ya i have kendo numeric text box in first column... i need to focus that numeric textbox.. and this table is dynamically generated one

Comment: @Vicky:Try the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

to focus textbox inside td use:

```
$('table#myTable tr:last td:first input').focus();
```

Comment: If your input is in the second column use  $("#myTable tr:last td:nth-child(2) input").focus();

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('table tr#myid').find('input:first').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the last tr and first column directly and focus. This will work out

```
$("#tbl").on("blur", ".last:last", function(){
     $("#tbl").append('<tr><td><input type="text" autofocus/></td><td><input type="text" class="last" /></td></tr>');
     $("#tbl tr:last td:first input").focus();

});
```

If you are seeing the output, by focusing after opening console , use

```
setTimeout(function() { $("#tbl tr:last td:first input").focus() }, 3000);
```

and click in broswer window after console. This will auto focus on the first addition input element